# Redshift: Temp table returning no results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, temp-tables

I am trying to add week numbers to a temp Redshift table and two things are peculiar to me.

1. After running the query the first time, I get a 1table already exists` error, which defeats the purpose of the temp keyword. Does it not function as expected?
2. When I query this table despite it already existing, no rows are returned. What's going on here?

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weeks_in_year_table;

CREATE TEMP TABLE weeks_in_year_table (
    week_num INT
);

INSERT INTO weeks_in_year_table VALUES
     (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9), (10),
    (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20),
    (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30),
    (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40),
    (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50),
    (51), (52);
    
SELECT * FROM weeks_in_year_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables persist for the duration of a database connection session.
If you want to re-run the code snippet more than once, prefix it with a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` query (shown below).

Retry the entire snippet again? Works for me.

```sql
-- Create the temporary table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weeks_in_year_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE weeks_in_year_table (
    week_num INT
);

-- Populate the temporary table with values from 1 to 52 using VALUES statement
INSERT INTO weeks_in_year_table
VALUES
    (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9), (10),
    (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20),
    (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30),
    (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39), (40),
    (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49), (50),
    (51), (52);

-- Display the contents of the temporary table
SELECT * FROM weeks_in_year_table;
```